# I keep getting out of bounds error how do i fix this?

Tags: java

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a word");
String line = scan.nextLine();
String pig = "";
int a = line.length();

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

while (y < a) {
    int b = line.indexOf(" ");

    if (line.substring(x, x + 1).equals("a") || 
            line.substring(x, x + 1).equals("e") || 
            line.substring(x, x + 1).equals("i") || 
            line.substring(x, x + 1).equals("o") || 
            line.substring(x, x + 1).equals("u"))
    {
        pig = line.substring(x, b - 1);
    }

    else {
        pig = line.substring(b - 1, x + 2) + line.charAt(x);
    }

    line = line.substring(b + 1);
    y++;
}

System.out.println(pig);
```

I'm suppose to convert the words in any sentence into pig latin if the word starts with a vowel just add way at the end if it starts with a consonant bring the first letter to the back and add way

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at
java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source) at pig_latin.main(Firstname_Lastname.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message/stack trace when asking questions

Comment: string has a startswith() method

Comment: You never update x how would you expect your code to work ?

Comment: I think you must update x in while loop instead of y!

Comment: @AliAmiri he needs to update both !

Comment: @StackFlowed but he didnt use y at all, I think y is just a iterator.

Comment: @AliAmiri yes but he want to keep it in bounds !

Comment: @StackFlowed a for loop do the work, but you are right any way

Comment: I suspect `x` should *not* be updated, and in fact it is not necessary at all, since he's updating `line` each time through the loop.  But I'm not sure what his plan is.  There are definitely other problems.

Comment: so do  i take out my y or x?

Comment: i really need help im in the 10th grade taking advanced placement computer science i gotta get this hw in by tmm :( :(

Answer (score 2):

Your method for tracking the words in the line is a problem use `String.split(" ")` to break the line into a series of words and then your while loop can be

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
for(String word:words) {
   // do pig latin on word
}
```

I suspect it's the substring on `line` that's failing as you don't terminate correctly when you've processed all words because the variable `y` is based on characters, where your algorithm is chunking words.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is

```
int b = line.indexOf(" ");
```

If you read the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)). It will return -1 if string is not found.
So if b becomes -1 then these lines will be evaluated like:

```
pig = line.substring(x, -2);
```

or

```
pig = line.substring(-2, x + 2) + line.charAt(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `pig = line.substring(x, b - 1);` you are assuming that b is initialized with a positive int, which would only be true if when you evaluate `int b = line.indexOf(" ");` there actually was a space in the String. If there wasn't, `b`'s value will be -1, and when you subtract an additional 1 from that, you are attempting to call `subString` with a value that is out of the String's bounds.